# Windows Phone 8.1 MediaCapture's FocusAsync does not work

Tags: c#, camera, windows-phone-8.1, focus

I'm implementing a Windows Phone 8.1 App with a QR Code reader. I use ZXing.NET to analyze the taken image and try to parse the QR. To increase it's efficiency I also set autofocus to the camera. It works pretty well at the first start, but not with the second try (f.e. after suspend - resume or restart capturing). As I tested, the FocusAsync method doesn't return sometimes and blocks everything.

What happens here? What could be the problem?

Here is my current code.

Focus

```
var focusSettings = new Windows.Media.Devices.FocusSettings();
focusSettings.AutoFocusRange = Windows.Media.Devices.AutoFocusRange.Normal;
focusSettings.Mode = Windows.Media.Devices.FocusMode.Auto;

CaptureManager.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl.Configure(focusSettings);
```

MainProcess

```
... Initialization ...  

ImageEncodingProperties imaggeProperties = ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg();
imaggeProperties.Width = ViewModel.ImageWidth;
imaggeProperties.Height = ViewModel.ImageHeight;

InMemoryRandomAccessStream memoryStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();

LoggingAdapter.Instance.WriteDebugLog("Scanning is in progress. " + Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId);       
await CaptureManager.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl.FocusAsync();
await CaptureManager.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(imaggeProperties, memoryStream);
LoggingAdapter.Instance.WriteDebugLog("Photo captured.");

var bcReader = new BarcodeReader();

... Processing the barcode ...
```

Cleaning

```
if (CaptureManager != null)
{
   if (InProgress)
   {
     InProgress = false;
     await CaptureManager.StopPreviewAsync();
   }
   CaptureManager.Dispose();
   Capture.Source = null;
  }
```

Thanks for advance!

Comment: How do you handle the suspend & resume, and the handling of the media capture?

Comment: In case of suspend I get a deferral and call the CleanCapture method. By cancelling happens the same, but without deferral, of course. Resuming is not handled, it's absolutely okay to let the user to start it again.

Comment: I succeeded to implement a working solution. I set the the WaitForFocus to false in the FocusSettings and it seems to be working fine, also with suspending or cancelling.

Comment: If you add that as an answer, we can vote it up for you :)

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded to implement a working solution. I set the the WaitForFocus to false in the FocusSettings and it seems to be working fine, also with suspending or cancelling.